# How to have multiple RabbitMQ queues on the same Spring listener

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I've an application that works in multiple countries, they're grouped per continent (i.e: `England`, `Portugal`, `France` and `Belgium` are grouped in the `EUROPE` cluster), but there are some countries that are entirely separate on it's own cluster.

I've something like user deletion and user creation, as follows:
`user-creation-queue-XX` and `user-deletion-queue-XX` where `XX` is the country code (i.e: `PT`, `EN`, `FR` and so on).

Right now, I only have a single method, which works:

```
@Component
public class UsertListener {

 @RabbitListener(queues = "#{rabbitConfiguration.getQueueNames()}")
public void createUser(@Payload User user) {}
}
```

`createUser` listens to `user-creation-queue-PT` `user-creation-queue-FR` `user-creation-queue-EN`, which is returned by `getQueueNames` method.
Now I need to add another listener to another queue (user deletion) that has dozens of variations.

How do I listen to multiple different queues where each queue have dozens of variations?

@Edit: I know the rough path for this would be to have a method for each queue, I'm just wondering if there's a better and cleaner way of doing it.

@Edit 2: By "multiple" variation of the same queue, I mean that I'd have multiple `user-creation-queue-XX` where `XX` is the country code, each country having a variation of that `user-creation-queue-` queue.

Comment: You question is not clear. What are those `dozens of variations`? What is still wrong with your existing approach via `#{rabbitConfiguration.getQueueNames()}` ? Another solution would be to leverage routing capabilities of RabbitMQ exchanges and bindings into queues. This way your listener could just subscribe to its only queue and it can be bound by some specific pattern(s) to the data from exchange.

Comment: Sorry, I tought it was pretty clear with the examples (`user-creation-queue-PT`, `user-creation-queue-EN`, `user-creation-queue-US`... Those are the variations of the `user-creation-queue`). Using `#{rabbitConfiguration.getQueueNames()}` would force me to have a different method for each queue variation (`user-creation-queue-XX` and `user-deletion-queue-XX`, which is what I want to avoid. And I cannot do it trough Rabbit exchange, as all instances would listen to the same group of queue and I can't control which one listens to each (I'm forced to use a single exchange for my project.)

Comment: Right. There is no way in RabbitMQ to subscribe to a pattern, so we are forced to use a list of those queue names. You can calculate them at runtime and add them manually to the listener container assigned to that `@RabbitListener`. See `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer()` API. And then `MessageListenerContainer.setQueueNames()`.

Comment: That's a shame. But thanks, I'll check the docs as you suggested! Thank you very much!